# Ошибка на IPB форуме

Tags: php

Вообщем, есть IPB форум. Если заходишь в разделы форумов, то форум отображается, но с ошибкой:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/p50193/www/play-mp3.ru/public/style_images/engraved/_php/IPBForumSkins.php on line 36

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/p50193/www/play-mp3.ru/public/style_images/engraved/_php/IPBForumSkins.php on line 41
```

Вот файл IPBForumSkins.php:

```
<?php
class IPBForumSkins{
    static public $_instance;
    static public function init(){
        if(self::$_instance == null)
            self::$_instance = new IPBForumSkins_Functions(ipsRegistry::instance());
        return self::$_instance;
    }
}
class IPBForumSkins_Functions{
    protected $registry;
    protected $DB;
    protected $settings;
    protected $request;
    protected $lang;
    protected $member;
    protected $memberData;
    protected $cache;
    protected $caches;
    public $topic_data;
    public function __construct(ipsRegistry $registry){
        $this->registry   =  $registry;
        $this->DB         =  $this->registry->DB();
        $this->settings   =& $this->registry->fetchSettings();
        $this->request    =& $this->registry->fetchRequest();
        $this->lang       =  $this->registry->getClass('class_localization');
        $this->member     =  $this->registry->member();
        $this->memberData =& $this->registry->member()->fetchMemberData();
        $this->cache      =  $this->registry->cache();
        $this->caches     =& $this->registry->cache()->fetchCaches();
    }

    public function loadAvatars( &$topic_data ){
        $members = array();
        $members_ids = array();
        foreach( $topic_data as $tid => $data )
            $members_ids[ $data['starter_id'] ] = $data['starter_id'];
        $members = IPSMember::load( array_keys( $members_ids ), 'core,extendedProfile' );
        foreach($members as $member )
            $members_avatars[ $member['member_id'] ] = IPSMember::buildAvatar( $member );
        foreach( $topic_data as $tid => $data )
            $topic_data[ $tid ]['starter_avatar'] = $members_avatars[ $data['starter_id'] ];
        return $topic_data;
    }
}
?>
```

Т.к в PHP я дно, прошу помощи у вас, уважаемые профессионалы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, найдите, где именно выводится `foreach` и напишите `if(!empty($members))` или на что там у вас ругается... Это "скрытие" проблемы, а не решение, решение (если оно необходимо) уже надо искать у фрилансеров.

Answer (score 0):

С кодом всё ок, надо копать глубже. Это только под вашей учётной записью или косяк "по умолчанию"?

Так же форум еще "как есть" или уже обвешан модами? Если моды, отключайте, а лучше удаляй по 1... с последнего установленного. И будет вам счастье, 90%, что криво встал какой-либо из аддонов.

Comment: Нет, нет, нет! Никаких модов и хуков нету! Стоит только "форум" и "Пользователи". В смысле по умолчанию? Видят эту ошибку все.

Comment: в студию листинг function loadAvatars

Answer (score 0):

В переводе на понятный, ваша ошибка звучит как "в $topic_data ерунда какая-то". Проверьте, существует ли такой массив и что в нем творится.
А если в php вы дно, самое время погуглить и почерпнуть новых знаний.